# How to save time zone information in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find out if it is possible to save the date time zone into a
file in R.
Lets create a date/time variable set to EST time.

```r
x <- as.POSIXct("2015-06-01 12:00:00", tz = "EST")
x
#> [1] "2015-06-01 12:00:00 EST"

lubridate::tz(x)
#> [1] "EST"

tmpfile <- tempfile()
```

I will save this date information (which is in EST time) using base R,
`readr` and `data.table` to see how the information is preserved.

**Base R version**

The date gets converted to UTC and the time is not changed.

```r
write.csv(data.frame(x = x), tmpfile)
df <- read.csv(tmpfile)

df
#>   X                   x
#> 1 1 2015-06-01 12:00:00

lubridate::tz(df$x)
#> [1] "UTC"
```

**tibble/readr version**

It gets converted to UTC and the time is formatted as UTC as described in
the help. Time is now 17:00:00.

> … POSIXct values are formatted as ISO8601 with a UTC timezone Note:
> POSIXct objects in local or non-UTC timezones will be converted to UTC
> before writing.

```r
readr::write_csv(tibble::tibble(x = x), tmpfile)
df <- readr::read_csv(tmpfile)
#> Rows: 1 Columns: 1
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> dttm (1): x
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   x                  
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2015-06-01 17:00:00

lubridate::tz(df$x)
#> [1] "UTC"
```

**data.table version**

The date gets converted to UTC and the time is formatted as UTC as described in
the help. Time is now also 17:00:00.

```r
data.table::fwrite(data.table::data.table(x = x), tmpfile)
df <- data.table::fread(tmpfile)

df
#>                      x
#> 1: 2015-06-01 17:00:00

lubridate::tz(df$x)
#> [1] "UTC"
```

Is it possible to preserve the time zone when saving a file? If the user is
not paying attention, this can go silently and create issues.

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: As @zephryl hinted, you really need to think about proper serialization.  Which csv text files are not.  Writing as UTC is by the way rather common and the truly only portable way. "Where your analysis runs" reallis metadata often encoded in `TZ` or local system timezone info.  It simply is a tricky problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would have thought there might have been a universal way to save this information. For example, an offset after Z like: 2015-06-01T17:00:00Z-5.

Comment: The parsers don't reliably read it back (based _e.g._ on Boost's which I use in `anytime`). Surprising, but common.  For example in R itself right in `help(strptime)` you get `‘%Z’ (Output only.)` and `%z` a warning that `For input R currently supports it on all platforms.` implying this could change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving to an `.RDS` is often the best choice to preserve an object exactly as it’s represented in R. In this case, it preserves timezone without conversion:

```
saveRDS(data.frame(x = x), tmpfile)
df <- readRDS(tmpfile)

df
#                    x
# 1 2015-06-01 12:00:00

lubridate::tz(df$x)
# [1] "EST"

df$x
# [1] "2015-06-01 12:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Yep. Or `fst` or `qs` or writing to a database (with date type `datetime with tz`) or ... really any _binary_ format that respects the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply paste the time zone on to the end of the datetime string.

```r
x <- as.POSIXct("2015-06-01 12:00:00", tz = "EST")
df <- data.frame(x = paste(as.character(x), lubridate::tz(x)))

tmpfile <- tempfile()

write.csv(df, tmpfile, row.names = FALSE)

new_df <- read.csv(text = csv)

new_df
#> x
#> 1 2015-06-01 12:00:00 EST

as.POSIXct(new_df$x, strsplit(new_df$x, ' ')[[1]][3])
#> [1] "2015-06-01 12:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Parsers often don't read TZ infoon input though.